# Chrome 80 POST from Flash: no cookies, Origin null (not cross-site)

Tags: google-chrome, flash, cookies, http-headers

Users have started having problems with Flash-based traffic under Chrome 80: Cookies are not being sent with `POST` requests.

I'm aware of the `SameSite` [updates](https://www.chromium.org/updates/same-site), but our traffic is all same-domain, so I assumed this wouldn't affect us.

Debugging the request headers from the debug tools:

[image: Chrome debug tools]

Here's what I note:

In an older version of Chrome 73:

- there are no `Sec-Fetch-*` headers
- `Origin` header is always correct
- cookies are sent properly

In Chrome 80, GET requests:

- `Origin` is correct, and cookies are sent
- now has `Sec-Fetch-*` headers
- the `Sec-Fetch-Site` cookie says `cross-site` -- **Is this right? This is determined by the browser, correct? Why would Chrome label the traffic as cross-site?** - the request URL is the same as my page, same as `window.location.hostname`.

In Chrome 80, POST requests:

- `Sec-Fetch-*` cookies same as GET
- the `Origin` header is `null` - **wait, why? This also is assigned by the browser, right? Why null?**
- cookies are not sent

This makes absolutely no sense to me. It's always worked, and we don't use multiple domains, and our cookies are `secure` and `httponly`. Can someone help me understand:

1. why Chrome 80 would label my requests as `Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site`?
2. why Chrome 80 would send `Origin: null` and no cookies for POSTs?

Comment: Does your cookie have SameSite=None and Secure flag?

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing the same problem. For the post request from Flash, sometimes the request doesn't contain cookies at all, sometimes it only contains one cookie key (I have multiple keys in my cookie). It looks like a bug in Chrome 80, unless they did it on purpose b/c they want to kill Flash for a long time.

Comment: I really wonder if it's "on purpose / don't care". But I created a small testcase, which didn't experience the problem. So now I'm very confused... Do you, by chance, use a crossdomain.xml file?

Comment: Hi, I am facing the same issue, sometime the JSESSIONID cookie is transmitted in the POST request, sometimes not. Because, the JSESSIONID cookie did not have SameSite=None and Secure flag. Please, read more about it here: https://docs.adobe.com/content/help/en/target/using/implement-target/before-implement/privacy/google-chrome-samesite-cookie-policies.html